# Is it possible to browse by Google eBook topic?

Tags: google-books

I am trying to find some books to read in the "Computers & Internet" section of [Google Books](http://books.google.com/ebooks).

The only option I am seeing is to search for books I think are available. Is it possible to browse by topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Visit this link: http://books.google.com/books